# Python:how to call def in class

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I practice Scrapy and want to ask a question:

I know how to use def printTW when it out of the class
How can I calling it when I write it inside class  ?
My code is here: 
Please teach me

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from yahoo.items import YahooItem

def printTW(original_line):
    for words in original_line:
        print words.encode('utf-8')     

class MySpider(Spider):   
    name = "yahoogo"
    start_urls = ["https://tw.movies.yahoo.com/chart.html"]  

    #Don't know how to calling this
    #def printTW(original_line):
    #    for words in original_line:
    #        print words.encode('utf-8')     

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//tr"):
            movie_description = sel.xpath("td[@class='c3']/a/text()").extract()
            printTW(movie_description)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call instance method, you need to qualify the method with `self`.

```
self.printTW(movie_description)
```

And the method should have a `self` as the first parameter:

```
def printTW(self, original_line):
    for words in original_line:
        print words.encode('utf-8')
```

Because the `printTW` does not use any instance attribute, you can define the method as static method (or you can define it as function, not a method).

```
@staticmethod
def printTW(original_line):
    for words in original_line:
        print words.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the function as global within the method you wish to call it, like so:

```
def parse(self, response):
    global printTW
    for sel in response.xpath("//tr"):
        movie_description = sel.xpath("td[@class='c3']/a/text()").extract()
        printTW(movie_description)
```

Comment: `global printTW` is not necessary.